# Accessing a private key in a MetaMask wallet

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I have a simple Dapp and I want to sign a transaction but I don't have the private key as a string.

The user is using a MetaMask wallet. After they grant web3 access to their account, how can I access the private key to sign a transaction?

```
const signPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY);
// PRIVATE_KEY is what I'm trying to get.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metamask doesn't share the private key directly for security reasons. And sometimes it doesn't even have the key - for instance when the user is using the Metamask UI to operate a hardware wallet account.

You'll need to construct the transaction object and pass it to the [ethereum.request()](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-request-args) method. This will open the Metamask window where the user can sign or decline the transaction request.

*Code example is pretty straightforward and is in the linked documentation.*

Answer (score 2):

MetaMask does not give you access to a private key and never will.

The whole point of the wallet is to protect the user against malicious Dapps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you would sign your Metamask transaction:

```
export const mintNFT = async(url, name, description) => {
    
    //error handling
    if (url.trim() == "" || (name.trim() == "" || description.trim() == "")) { 
        return {
            success: false,
            status: "❗Please make sure all fields are completed before minting.",
        }
    }
  
    //make metadata
    const metadata = new Object();
    metadata.name = name;
    metadata.image = url;
    metadata.description = description;

    //pinata pin request
    const pinataResponse = await pinJSONToIPFS(metadata);
    if (!pinataResponse.success) {
        return {
            success: false,
            status: " Something went wrong while uploading your tokenURI.",
        }
    } 
    const tokenURI = pinataResponse.pinataUrl;  

    //load smart contract
    window.contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);//loadContract();

    //set up your Ethereum transaction
    const transactionParameters = {
        to: contractAddress, // Required except during contract publications.
        from: window.ethereum.selectedAddress, // must match user's active address.
        'data': window.contract.methods.mintNFT(window.ethereum.selectedAddress, tokenURI).encodeABI() //make call to NFT smart contract 
    };
  
    //sign transaction via Metamask
    try {
        const txHash = await window.ethereum
            .request({
                method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                params: [transactionParameters],
            });
        return {
            success: true,
            status: "✅ Check out your transaction on Etherscan: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/" + txHash
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            success: false,
            status: " Something went wrong: " + error.message
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we're signing a transaction to mint an NFT. You can check out more details here: https://docs.alchemyapi.io/alchemy/tutorials/nft-minter#step-8-implement-the-mintnft-function